# Vector Field of Torus

Tags: differential-topology, vector-analysis

Explicitly construct a differentiable vector field $W$ in the torus.

Meridians of  $T^2$ parameterized by arc length, for all $p \in T^2$, define $W (p)$ as the velocity vector of the meridian passing through $p$.

Maybe could help

$x=(R+r \cos \phi)\cos \theta$;

$y=(R+r \cos \phi)\sin \theta$;

$z=r \sin \phi$

Where $\theta, \phi \in [0, 2\pi[$
Thanks

Comment: Is the first sentence the question and the rest is what you've tried? If it doesn't have to be nonvanishing you could easily make one on a coordinate chart, then multiply by a bump function to make it go to zero outside the chart.

Comment: Since you can represent $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, just take a $\mathbb{Z}^2$-equivariant vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Matt or just make it identically zero, can't be much more explicit than that...

Comment: The parameterization may be from an open, and $[0,2\pi[$ is not open, right? I think we need more than one parameterization to cover the torus, what do you think? Other doubt I've get is because I did the calculus and get the velocities with size $r$, ie, not parameterization b arc lenght. Many thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the second question is actually a part of the exercise. Hint: the variable that parametrizes each meridian is $\phi$. Hence, the velocity vector of the meridian is the partial derivative with respect to $\phi$.